# creating a new column with conditional group by

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to figure a way to sum a column based on conditions are create a new column with the aggregated values.

[image]

I need to sum column D based based on column condition from Column A, B and C. Value 1 in column A is the exception. The output that is required is as follows -

[image]

Where a new column E is created that sums Column D(2958673+2166646) by the condition of Column A(10,12) and Column B(20) and Column C(3) in Row 1. Similarly, Column D(1799504) by the condition of Column A(12) and Column B(20) and Column C(4) in Row 2

Answer (score 2):

This is perhaps a comment, but it is too long.

I simply do not follow the logic that you want to implement.  Your results can be produced by a simple query with filtering:

```
select a, b, c, d as d, d as e
from t
where a = 1;
```

EDIT:

Perhaps this is what you want?

```
select 1, b, c,
       sum(d) filter (where a = 1) as d,
       sum(d) filter (where a in (10, 12)) as e
from t
group by b, c;
```